# Garry's Mod Tool-Gun Lua Error

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I have decompiled the old Pikmin add-on for Garry's Mod because it's producing the following error:

> [ERROR] workshop/lua/sv_pikmin.lua:38: attempt to call global 'ValidEntity' (a nil value)
>     1. v - workshop/lua/sv_pikmin.lua:38
>      2. Call - lua/includes/modules/hook.lua:84
>       3. unknown - gamemodes/sandbox/entities/weapons/gmod_tool/shared.lua:279

This section of code is on line 38:

```
    local function DontToolMe(ply, tr, tool)
if (ValidEntity(tr.Entity) && tr.Entity:GetClass() == "pikmin_onion" || tr.Entity:GetClass() == "pikmin" || tr.Entity:GetClass() == "pikmin_model") then
    if (tool == "duplicator") then
        return false;
    end
end
return true;
```

end

Line 38 is specifically the "if" statement with the "ValidEntity" keyword.

I would like to somehow be able to update this fantastic add-on so we can use it along with the tool-gun.

I have the whole project here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwr6tf5HSyxyRXZ0c2VkQmEtU2M/view?usp=sharing

Thanks,
Pikmin25.

Answer (score 2):

ValidEntity is not a function in your scope. Therefor you cannot call it.

I don't know where you got that function from and I'm no Gary's Mod expert. But the reference documentation lists a function IsValid(entity). Maybe you can use this instead as you are obviously trying to validate an entity.

So try to replace `ValidEntity(tr.Entity)` by `IsValid(tr.Entity)`

Comment: Well, this is a very old plugin which has been re-uploaded several times. It doesn't surprise me that it has deprecated code.

I'm just trying to update it so I can use the tool-gun with it enabled.